# RTSP streaming iOS 6 using WoWza Server

Tags: objective-c, ios6

Does any one knows about `RTSP` streaming using `WOWza` Server ?

I want to play it on a `MPMoviePlayer` controller in `iOS6` but it shows not enough buffer to keep it up. My webservice urls work fine because I have also checked them using a browser but I can't find anything about `RTSP` streaming.

Does any one have any tutorials about `RTSP` streaming on iPhone using `WOWza` Server ?

Answer (score 0):

rtsp streaming is not possible on iPhone, iPad and iPod touch. Please refer to the following link.

http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?62

Comment: rtsp streaming is not possible, that is not a true statement, its just not possible using the Apple sdk.

Comment: @MichelleCannon that's why I said it's not possible on "iPhone, iPad or iPod touch"

Comment: You can use 3rd party Api on iPhone, iPad,iPod touch

Comment: Certainly, it's possible to do. For example using ffmpeg. In my project kxmovie (https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmovie) I can play such link rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov from Wowza Media Server

Answer (score 0):

MPMoviePlayer only supports HTTP live streaming. to have RTSP working on iPhone, you must implement your client on the iOS.

There is library live555 which implements for you, but you must integrate it with the code. Also decoding of the stream must be implemented in software, by you or a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 0):

Wowza support re-restreaming the content as HLS, if this is your wowza server than there are easy instructions on the www.wowza.com site, if its not perhaps they are streaming HLS.

If you have to use rtsp, there are several good players available on the app store, or you can build your own using lib 555 as mentioned or one of our open or closed sourced frameworks.

https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/AVDemoPlay2L